# Passing variable data to string date

Tags: php

i want to pass variable in date function. it works while passing only one variable but if i pass two variable one for month and other for year then it does not work Please resolve

```
<?php
 $m = 'June';
 $y = '2011';
 echo $cutoff = date('m-d-Y', strtotime( $m . '01' . ' 2011'));
 echo '<br>';
 echo $nono = date('m-t-Y', strtotime( $m . '01' . $y)); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add space to your parameter

```
echo $nono = date('m-t-Y', strtotime( $m . ' 01 ' . $y));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your parameters, you need to add a space between day and year :

Not working

```
 echo $nono = date('m-t-Y', strtotime( $m . '01' . $y));
```

Working :

```
 echo $nono = date('m-t-Y', strtotime( $m . '01 ' . $y));
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
echo $nono = date('m-t-Y', strtotime( $m . '01' . $y));
```

to

```
echo $nono = date('m-t-Y', strtotime( $m . ' 01 ' . $y));
```